# axios post without refresh page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
methods: {
        onShowModal(idWinnerPrize, idPrize, curUser) {
            this.userEdit = _.cloneDeep(curUser);
            if (idWinnerPrize === idPrize) {
                this.confirmAward = false;
                this.isDelete = true;
                this.isFull = false;
                this.userEdit.prize = null;
            } else {
                this.confirmAward = true;
                this.isDelete = false;
                let countPrize = this.winners.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                    if (cur.prize_id === idPrize) {
                        acc += 1;
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, 0);
                const currentPrize = this.prizes.find(
                    item => item.id === idPrize
                );
                if (currentPrize && currentPrize.quantity <= countPrize) {
                    this.isFull = true;
                } else {
                    this.userEdit.prize = idPrize;
                    this.isFull = false;
                }
            }
            this.showModal = true;
        },
        onCloseModal() {
            this.showModal = false;
            this.notify = false;
        },
```

this is my function show and close modal, and use axios.post to update

```
 async onEdit() {
            let res = null;
            let userIndex = this.winners.findIndex(
                item => item.id == this.userEdit.id
            );
            res = await axios.post( this.isFull ? REMOVE_PRIZE : EDIT_PRIZE, { id: this.userEdit.id, prize_id: this.userEdit.prize } ).then((res) => { return res.data }).catch((error => {
                return error
            }));
            res = true;
            if (userIndex > -1 && res) {
                this.winners[userIndex] = this.userEdit;
            }
            this.showModal = false;
        },
        updated() {
            this.prizes = this.contest.prizes;
            this.winners = this.posts.data;
        }
    },
    props: ['contest', 'actionUrl', 'method', 'posts'],
    data() {
        return {
            notify: true,
            showModal: false,
            confirmAward: true,
            isDelete: false,
            isFull: false,
            userEdit: {},
            prizes: [],
            winners: []
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.showModal = true;
    }
};
```

that my Vue component, I want to update the page without refresh the page after I click on edit, I don't know why Axios post can't update data. If I update, I need to refresh the page to see my updated data

Comment: where is your edit button html put that as well

Comment: <button
                        type="button"
                        v-if="!notify && !isFull"
                        :class="[
                            'btn px-sm-32',
                            isDelete ? 'btn-red' : 'btn-blue'
                        ]"
                        @click="onEdit"
                    >
                        同意する
                    </button>

Comment: so when your click this page is refresh ?

Comment: i want this page no refresh, but when i click data change, I want page update without refresh.

Comment: have you try ? is it refreshing ?

Comment: What does the template look like? Specifically, if the submit button is a <button type="submit"> within a <form> tag, that is going to submit the form by default.  You could use a <button type="button"> instead, or use preventDefaults() somewhere in the process.